# How to handle asynchronous operation in Workmanager Android?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using workmanager to upload image file to server and want to pass uploaded imagepath to next worker but `Result.success(output)` gets called before upload function complete.

```
class UploadImageWorker(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : RxWorker(context, workerParameters) {


override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        return Single.fromCallable {
         //UploadImageFile()
         //updating output 
       }.map{
         Result.success(output)
         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you share the code of "UploadImageFile" method?

Answer (score 0):

Success, in this case, is only reporting that the job fired successfully, it is not a measure of the work itself.

You should just use the worker to hand off the work and do something like:

`MyFactory.ImageFactory.UploadImageFile(file)`

Then inside your ImageFactory use Observer pattern or something similar to subscribe to the state of your UploadImageFile. This would be the true measure of success.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RxWorker`. You can return a `Single<Result>`. Read the documentation for `RxWorker` for more information.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/RxWorker